# C++: bitset doesn't work properly

Tags: c++, bitset

I need a `std::bitset<64>` for my project.  But while printing the number something goes wrong:

```
unsigned long long var = 18446462598732906495ULL;
std::cout << std::bitset<64>(var) << std::endl;
```

it prints:

```
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001111111111111111
```

I would expect it to print:

```
1111111111111111000000000000000000000000000000001111111111111111
```

What is going wrong?

I'm working with DevC++ in 64-bit machine.

Comment: It depends if the compiler supports 64-bit integer to construct bitset.

Comment: It works with c++11 [here](https://ideone.com/Dforll), and fails with C++03 [here](https://ideone.com/cE4laH).

Answer (score 3):

The `bitset` constructor you're using takes `unsigned long` not `unsigned long long` so presumably the compiler is throwing away the bits that don't fit in `unsigned long`. I think you're going to have to iterate over your input value and set the bits individually.

Comment: @MarkB, in C++11 constructor has ULL as a parameter, but not in C++03

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can see, in C++98 bitset has 3 constructors, one of them is unsigned long (which is 32bit on Windows 64).

But! In C++11 it was rectified and constructor now has unsigned long long as a parameter (which is 64bit on Windows 64).

So, change your settings to use C++11 standard

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/bitset/

Comment: Of course `unsigned long long` wasn't even a standard type before C++11.